# Replacing a varying string after search criteria using SED

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

Inside a shell script amidst error checking loops, I have a command that contains a variable that must be updated once an hour.  The command as it exists currently is (the line begins with a \t):

```
        /home/user/therm/therm -d /dev/ttyUSB0 -t host -O 44.0
```

In this case, I'm trying to replace the number that's after "-O".  This is a temperature in Fahrenheit, so it has the possibility of being a negative number or a positive number, and one, two, or three digits followed by a single decimal place.  So I have to be able to replace a variable that could be "-15.0", "7.2", "104.5", or any other combination - with a new variable that could also be any of the above.

I can force the "-O" setting to be the last thing on the line, which helps some.  But I can't count on anything else on that line except the file name, the "-d /dev/ttyUSB0" and the "-O" always being there.  In this particular shell script there are no other instances of "-O", but I might want to verify that the line has either the file name or the "-d /dev/ttyUSB0" on it to avoid replacing a flag on some other line in the script.

The new variable is parsed (via xmllint and sed) from an XML file grabbed via wget once an hour.  This shell script I need to edit is ran by cron every 5 minutes, only receiving the new string once an hour.  The new string can be passed to sed via a variable, or as a file with only the number and a \n in it.

Any thoughts or brilliant ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: why don't you try something and let us know what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
# string to be replaced
r=123.4
sed "s/\(-O *\)[^[:blank:]]*/\1$r/" file
/home/user/therm/therm -d /dev/ttyUSB0 -t host -O 123.4
```

Pattern `-O *[^[:blank:]]*` will find literal `-O` followed by 0 or more spaces and then the *non-space* string.

Comment: It's good that you handle optional space after the `-O`; I'd be tempted to make the output use `-O 123.4` with a single space — the canonical form.  That only requires minor tweaks: `sed "s/-O *[^[:blank:]]*/-O $r/" file` (which loses the capture because the output is fixed even if the input is not).  You could even use: `sed "s/-O[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*/-O $r/" file`.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for your edit. Yes `sed "s/-O[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*/-O $r/" file` is pretty good suggestion if output must have single space after `-O`. I was just trying to keep output same as input before replaced string.

Comment: Thank you both - that seems to work perfectly. Much appreciated. Mind walking me through how `sed "s/-O[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*/-O $r/" file` does the replacement? I'm getting lost after the first blank. Looks like I need to spend some more time studying regex.

Comment: This regex pattern `-O[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*` is matching literal text `-O` followed by `0 or more spaces` followed by `0 or more non-spaces`. Replacement part is literal `-O` followed by space and your replacement variable `$r`

Comment: An additional comment on this ghost thread... it took me until today to truly understand what you explained here - that the asterisk was the count for the previous declaration (blank or non-blank). I had to update the sed string to match a second switch, and after a lot of failed searching and borked regex phrases, I finally came back here and really parsed what you said and the phrases... at which point I came up with this hideous but perfect string for my second switch match (-u):  s/-O[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*-u[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*/ . Thank you all again!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
awk '{$NF=($NF-32)/1.8;print}'
```

Comment: This appears to be converting the temperature in °F to a temperature in °C.  I don't think that is the transform that is requested.